# Can't find .config folder in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, configuration, settings

I'm reading instruction to move files into .config folder tree specifically  `~/.config/geany/filedefs/`, but can't find it in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally any .folder are hidden folders

`.config` is a hidden folder under home. You can view hidden files in any folder *View--> Show Hidden Files* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

Since `.config` is a hidden folder it will not appear in your File Manager by default. To be able to view it, open your home folder and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>. It will show all the hidden folders in your home directory.

To hide the folders, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> again.